# Datatable AJAX Data Parameter is not refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm stuck on a portion of my datatable Ajax reload. In the beginning of my javascript file I have the following:

```
var courtDateSelected;

docketCheckedInDataTable = $('#data-checked-in').DataTable({
        ajax: {
            type: "POST",
            url: base_url + '/courts/dockets/api/list1',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                'court_date_id': courtDateSelected,
                'checked_in': 'true',
            },
            error: function (xhr, error, code)
            {
                console.log(xhr);
                console.log(code);
            },
            "dataSrc": function (json) {
                //Make your callback here.
                $('#checkedInCount').html(json.data.length);
                return json.data;
            }
        },
        "paging": true,
        "dom": '<"datatable-header"f>rt<"datatable-footer"p>',
        "ordering": true,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "autoWidth": false,
        "searching": true,
        "info": false,
        "order": [],
        "columns": [
            {data: 'view', name: 'view', orderable: false},
            {data: 'docket_number', name: 'docket_number', orderable: false},
            {data: 'last_name', name: 'last_name', orderable: true},
            {data: 'first_name', name: 'first_name', orderable: false},
            {data: 'balance', name: 'balance', orderable: false},
            {data: 'actions', name: 'actions', orderable: false},
        ],
        language: {
            search: "_INPUT_",
            searchPlaceholder: "Search Keywords...",
            emptyTable: "There are no available dockets for the selected court session."
        }
    });
```

I have a date selector where it sets the variable's (courtDateSelected) value to the value selected and then sets off this script:

```
function reloadCheckinPageTables(){
    console.log('begin');
    console.log(courtDateSelcted);
    console.log('end');
    docketCheckedInDataTable.ajax.reload();
    docketDataTable.ajax.reload();
    docketPendingCheckoutDataTable.ajax.reload();
}
```

The problem is that my console log's the following:

```
begin
894
end
```

Which leads me to believe that the variable has been successfully updated, however, this variable's update value is not passed onto the data parameters in the DataTable.

Answer (score 1):

For dynamically calculated data, you should use [ajax.data](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) as a function. Something like:

```
 ajax: { 
   ...
   data: fundtion(d) {
     d.court_date_id = courtDateSelected;
     d.checked_in = 'true';
   }
   ...
```